# Launching a certain Oracle DB instance

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I have an Oracle database called A and a database called B on the same server node. There are two init.ora files for both of them. When I command `startup` in SQLPlus, the following error appears:

```
ORA-01103: database name 'B' in control file is not 'A'
```

I cannot delete B's init-file. How do I make it launch A database? Is there any key for startup to target a certain init-file?

Comment: Is it possible that the 'A' control file was replaced with a copy of the 'B" control file, or (more likely) the 'A' init.ora file with a copy of the 'B' init.ora? How did you set your environment before starting sqlplus (i.e. your ORACLE_SID environment parameter)?

Comment: The environment vars are set so that A is to be launched (ORACLE_SID and ORADATA). As for the files, there are both of them in the dbhome_1/dbs directory.

Comment: but does the initA.ora file really have the right content? sounds like it might be pointing to the 'B' control files.